# Delphi webbrowser - How to Get value from tag name inside id

Tags: delphi

i am using delphi 7 and making small program in which i use webbrowser to get value from tag inside id

here is html example of where value is saved

```
<div id="download" style="display: block;">

    <a style="display:none" href="blablabla"></a>
    <a href="Need This value"></a>
    <a style="display:none"blablabla"></a>
    <a style="display:none"blablabla"></a>
    <span style="margin-left:8px; color:#808080; overflow:hidden; white-space: nowrap"></span>
</div>
```

i can get innerHTML of id "download" 
my problem is after how to get value of "href" from tag "a"

Comment: Can you show us your code how you get the `download` div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `<a>` tag in question had a `name` or `id` assigned to it, you could have simply used the `IHTMLDocument2.anchors` collection to find it, for example:

```
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  Anchor: IHTMLAnchorElement;
  Value: String;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Anchor := Doc.anchors.item('name', 0) as IHTMLAnchorElement;
  Value := Anchor.href;
end;
```

But, since it does not have a `name` or `id`, you will have to dig through the DOM a little bit further, for example:

```
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument3;
  Download: IHTMLElement;
  Coll: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Anchor: IHTMLAnchorElement;
  Value: String;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument3;
  Download := Doc.getElementById('download') as IHTMLElement;
  Coll := Download.children as IHTMLElementCollection;
  Coll := Coll.tags('a') as IHTMLElementCollection;
  Anchor := Coll.item(1, 0) as IHTMLAnchorElement;
  Value := Anchor.href;
end;
```

Comment: Hello
thx this is nice example it works perfect
<a> tag is in "Download" id 
as you can see there are 4 <a> tags
your code shows me value of first <a> tag 
i need value of second <a> tag 
thx for your time

Comment: ok sorry for being stupid solved finally by
 Anchor := Coll.item(2, 3) as IHTMLAnchorElement; thx once again Remy lebeau (Y)

Comment: `IHTMLElementCollection` is 0-indexed. `item(1, 0)` returns the 2nd item, `item(2, 0)` returns the 3rd item, etc. You said you wanted the value of the 2nd `<a>` tag, so `item(1, 0)` would be correct. [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703928.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's the best solution, but it worked here:

```
function FindYourValue(block : string) : string;
var text, subtext : string;
    quant : integer;
begin
  text := block;
  if pos('<a href="',text) > 0 then
    subtext := copy(text,pos('<a href="',text) + 9,length(text));
  quant := pos('"',subtext);
  result := copy(subtext,1,9);
end;
```

Where `BLOCK` is the string you get from the `<div id="download" style="display: block;">` routine.

Comment: Thx i thought about doing this but size of value is not always same

Comment: It is not a good idea to parse source code rather than the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Remy Lebeau @RemyLebeau should work. But you might meet exception, if the HTML does not contain the element you are expecting. If you want to write your code in a more secure way, I'd suggest you use `Supports` to query the Html element interfaces.

```
function ExtractUrlExample: TStringList; 
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument3;
  Download: IHTMLElement;
  Coll: IHTMLElementCollection;
  I: Integer;
  Anchor: IHTMLAnchorElement;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  if Supports(WebBrowser1.Document, IHTMLDocument3, Doc) and
     Supports(Doc.getElementById('download'), IHTMLElement, Download) and
     Supports(Download.children, IHTMLElementCollection, Coll) and
     Supports(Coll.tags('a'), IHTMLElementCollection, Coll) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Coll.Length - 1 do
      if Supports(Coll.item(I, 0), IHTMLAnchorElement, Anchor) then
        Result.Add(Anchor.href); // The Url you want to extract
  end;
end;
```